# problem when get floatValue from NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am confusing and don't know why it's happen that when I get float from string.

I have an array of NSString, and when I get floatValue from these string object, they are not correct, for an example:

NSString object is "71.4" => floatValue is 71.4000013

NSString obtect is "71.45"=> floatValue is 71.4489839

Does anyone know the root cause and how to resolve, please help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the joys of floating point. These ARE 'correct'. Floating point values are very inaccurate due to how they're stored on the system.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding) is a much better explanation than I'll be able to give.

Comment: Thanks, I know the reason now!

Answer (score 0):

Try doubleValue.

Comment: In my case, I'd like to use value variable rather than pointer variable

Comment: At best, this answer is incomplete. Perhaps a more complete code example?